# How to get record from post table in laravel using eloquen relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have tow table first table is **posts** table and second table is **home_posts** table so i want to home_posts table (post_id) throw get record in posts table.

I was used hasMany() relationship in post model but not getting any record. I want only home_posts table post id record from posts table. I want home post table to post table record.

```
Post table
+----+-----------------+
| id | title           | 
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | Post 1          | 
| 2  | Post 3          |
| 26 | Post 4          | 
| 27 | Post 5          |
| 28 | Post 6          | 
| 29 | Post 7          | 
| 30 | Post 8          | 
| 32 | Post 9          | 
+----+-----------------+

home_post table
+----+------------+
| id | post_id    | 
+----+------------+
| 1  | 28         | 
| 2  | 29         |
| 3  | 2          |  
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Post** model:

```
public function home_posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\HomePost', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

In **HomePost** model:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

To get **post** through **home_post**:

```
$homePost = \App\HomePost::find(1);
$post = $homePost->post;
```

or

```
$posts = \App\HomePost::has('post')->get();
```

To get **home_post** through **post**:

```
$post = \App\Post::find(1);
$homePost = $homePost->home_posts;
```

or

```
$homePost = \App\Post::has('home_posts')->get();
```

For more detail read this: [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Hope it help you :)

Comment: I want home_post table post_id record 28,29,2 from post table.

Comment: edit answer ... $posts = \App\HomePost::whereHas('post')->get();

Comment: It's give error. Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, none given, but when i use with has() is work.

Comment: Thanks @Odin Thunder